# Get Selected Item ID of ListBox C++

Tags: c++, listbox, selecteditem

Im trying to make one simple program, that list few names in ListBox, and when selecting one of them, and clicking on one button should be load the data in few TextBoxes... All i need is the ID of the selected item of that ListBox because the data is in array and i can't get the info without that id.
So here is my code:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             this->listBox1->Items->Clear();
             if (sCount != 0) { 
                for (int i = 1; i <= sCount; i++) { 
                    String^ entry = gcnew System::String(s[i].Show().c_str()); 
                    this->listBox1->Items->Add(entry); //Listing the items from the array: s
                } 
             }
         }
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         s[++sCount].InsertStudent("Name",270,50); //This is how i'm adding items in the array
     }
private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         int i = this->listBox1->SelectedItem; //Trying to get the ListBox Item ID
         String^ entry = gcnew System::String(s[i].Show().c_str()); //Getting the Item from the array
         this->textBox1->Text = entry; //Placing the array item into the textBox1
     }
```

P.S. I want to do it in that way, because the array have class and there i put more than one items in one ID, but in the ListBox is listed only one of them.
Can someone help? Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself :)

Here is what i search, if someone come to this post:

```
int i = this->listBox1->SelectedIndex;
```